# How to delete/update specific data in txt file using C++

Tags: c++, file

I made a loop for a library system to show this menu.

```
cout << "1. Add a new book.\n2. Update a book.\n3. Delete a book.\n4. Show all 
books.\n5. Search book by ID.\n6. Search book by Name.\n7. Borrow a book.\n8. 
Exit." << endl;
cin >> choice;
while (choice >= 0 && choice <8) {
if (choice == 5) {
        int x;
        cout << "Enter the ID you want to search for" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        SearchByID(x);
        choice = 0;
    }
 cout << "1. Add a new book.\n2. Update a book.\n3. Delete a book.\n4. Show 
 all books.\n5. Search book by ID.\n6. Search book by Name.\n7. Borrow a 
 book.\n8. exit." << endl;
 cin >> choice;
 }
```

the SearchByID function is coded like that.

```
void SearchByID(int y)
{
bool found = false;
Book book;
string id, name, author, price, copies;
iLib >> id >> name >> author >> price >> copies;
while (iLib >> book.ID >> book.name >> book.author >> book.price >> book.copies) {
    if (book.ID == y) {
        cout << "Book is found:" << endl;
        cout << left << setw(4) << id << setw(15) << name << setw(15) << author << setw(8) << price << setw(8) << copies << endl;
        cout << left << setw(4) << book.ID << setw(15) << book.name << setw(15) << book.author << setw(8) << book.price << setw(8) << book.copies << endl << endl << endl;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found == false)
    cout << "Book is not found" << endl;
}
```

when i run it and search for a book by id it works fine, but when the function work is finished the while loop show this menu again, if i searched for the same book id it show me that it doesn't exist but at the start of the program it showed me that the book exist (which is right)
how can i fix that and where's the mistake.

SUMMARY: when i search for an existing ID for 2 times or more, the first time it works fine and the rest to show me that the book doesn't exist

Show all books code:-

```
if (choice == 4) { // show all books
        string id, name, author, price, copies;
        iLib >> id >> name >> author >> price >> copies;
        cout << left << setw(4) << id << setw(15) << name << setw(15) << author << setw(8) << price << setw(8) << copies << endl;
        while (iLib >> book.ID >> book.name >> book.author >> book.price >> book.copies) {
            cout << left << setw(4) << book.ID << setw(15) << book.name << setw(15) << book.author << setw(8) << book.price << setw(8) << book.copies << endl;
            cout << "================================================" << endl;
        }
        iLib.clear();
        iLib.seekg(0);
        choice = 0;
    }
```

Borrow code in UpdateOrDel function:-

```
void UpdateOrDel(int id, int s) {
if (s == 3) { // borrow
    while (!iLib.eof() && i <= 1) {
        string idd, name, author, price, copies;
        iLib >> idd >> name >> author >> price >> copies;
        oTmpLib << left << setw(4) << idd << setw(15) << name << setw(15) << author << setw(8) << price << setw(8) << copies << endl;
        i++;
    }
    while (iLib >> b.ID >> b.name >> b.author >> b.price >> b.copies) {
        if (b.ID == id) {
            found = true;
            oTmpLib << left << setw(4) << b.ID << setw(15) << b.name << setw(15) << b.author << setw(8) << b.price << setw(8) << b.copies - 1 << endl;
            cout << "Book has been Borrowed! \n \n" << endl;
        }
        else
            oTmpLib << left << setw(4) << b.ID << setw(15) << b.name << setw(15) << b.author << setw(8) << b.price << setw(8) << b.copies << endl;
    }
    iLib.clear();
    iLib.seekg(0);
    OLib.close();
    iLib.close();
    remove("library.txt");
    ofstream OLib("library.txt", ios::app);
    ifstream iLib("library.txt", ios::in);
    i = 1;
    while (!iTmpLib.eof() && i <= 1) {
        string idd, name, author, price, copies;
        iTmpLib >> idd >> name >> author >> price >> copies;
        OLib << left << setw(4) << idd << setw(15) << name << setw(15) << author << setw(8) << price << setw(8) << copies << endl;
        i++;
    }
    while (iTmpLib >> b.ID >> b.name >> b.author >> b.price >> b.copies) {
        OLib << left << setw(4) << b.ID << setw(15) << b.name << setw(15) << b.author << setw(8) << b.price << setw(8) << b.copies << endl;
    }
    iTmpLib.close();
    oTmpLib.close();
    remove("LibraryTemp.txt");
    if (found == false)
        cout << "Book is not found \n \n" << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iLib (which I think is your file, because you didn't show it's definition) contains a pointer to the position inside the file. If you want to make a new search from the beginning, you need to set it to the beginning again first:

```
iLib.clear();  
iLib.seekg(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for most of the menu but when i borrow a book and then try to show all the books it doesn't show anything.
Updated with more details